# ConcurrentModificationException when iterate through ImmutableMap.copyof()

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

Currently, I have a problem when I frequently iterating through a HashMap (1-time per second)

**I add new element to the map on the main thread** and **iterate the map on the other thread**

I return an ImmutableMap.copyOf() to iterate through it, and sometimes I add a new element to the map. But it throws me a ConcurrentModificationException

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
  at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:911) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:861) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
```

My pseudo-code:

```java
class Foo {
    private final Map<String, List<User>> userMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static void addUser(String houseId, User user) {
        if(!userMap.containsKey(houseId)) {
            userMap.put(houseId, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        List<User> list = userMap.get(houseId);
        list.add(user);
    }

    public static Map<String, List<User>> getAll() {
        return ImmutableMap.copyOf(userMap);
    }
}

// iterating task
// this task run one per second

class Task extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        for (List<User> listUser : Foo.getAll().values()) {
            for (User user : listUser) {
                user.sayHello(); // print hello
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that use an ImmutableMap.copyOf() will prevent me from this problem. Because I read that you should use an immutable copy of your list/map when iterating through it from other thread.

I think I "solve" this by using CopyOnWriteArrayList. But I'm really curious why it throws me an error.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Your english is good, don't apologize for it

Comment: It looks like your problem is that `ImmutableMap` is just shallowly immutable. The lists inside are still mutable. If you really want to provide a deep copy, you will need to copy all the lists too.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to look into it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the stack trace, the error occurs in the ArrayList, not the Map.
In method `addUser`, an element is added to the list via
`list.add(user);`

This operation might happen, while another thread loops over the elements with `for (User user : listUser)` causing the error.

When you exchange the ArrayList with a CopyOnWriteArrayList, the `list.add(user)` internally makes a copy and adds the new user into the copy. Therefore, a potentially running iteration is not affected since it loops over the old version of the array. So the running iteration will ignore the new value. Any new iterator will include the new value.

Comment: I have a quick question. Sorry, I'm not on my computer so I can't test. Will the synchronized block on the List object that I get from the map will prevent the ConcurrentModificationException? Thank you!

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. But as Michael already pointed out, the copyOf only does a shallow copy of the map. The contained lists remain in place.